# What's more efficient when delegating methods?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, jquery

I have a site full of AJAX so I need to delegate methods to document clicks, assuming I have jQuery library too.
I just want to know what's more efficient between these two codes:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delegate1', function(){
    doSomethingForDelegate1();
}).on('click', '.delegate2', function(){
    doSomethingForDelegate2();
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event){
    var element = $(event.target);
    if(element.hasClass('delegate1')){
        doSomethingForDelegate1();
    } else if(element.hasClass('delegate2')){
        doSomethingForDelegate2();
    }
})
```

I want to implement the code that will have less impact on client's execution time and therefore have a faster site. I know that maybe the difference won't be much but it's always better to work faster ;)

If there's a method that's faster than these 2 methods it's welcome too. Thanks.

If the difference isn't noticeable enough then I want to know what algorythm is cleaner, binding an event for each delegate or bind a single event and compare classes.

Comment: There's hardly a difference. At least, you won't notice the site to reasonably become faster.

Comment: Bind each handler as close to the target as possible, not to `document`.

Comment: Maybe that's true, then I'd like to know what algorythm is considered cleaner. I'm editing the question.

Comment: both chrome and firefox have profilers now, you could try using one of them to see is there is any noticeable difference.

Comment: As @FelixKling said it's better to bind the handler to the closest target, but I don't always contain the new elements on the same container, and if I bind the event to a specific class I could have an event for each container class I have on the site.

Comment: Perhaps you would have some luck creating an example at http://jsperf.com/ or finding one already created: http://jsperf.com/search?q=Event+binding. As you stated, the difference will be negligible, but IF you wanted to know jsperf will help you find out.

Comment: Did you look to see what jQuery is doing under the covers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd method can be efficient when there are many elements that are being added to the DOM at a later time. SO attaching a single event to the document and delegating can really speed up the application .

But if the number of elements created and needed to be attached are not huge, both should perform at the same rate..

I would go with the 1st approach as it is lot more cleaner.

Comment: In first example there's also only one event on `document`. Difference is that JQuery checks for target element internally.

Comment: I also thought the single event binding would be faster assuming that I could have 100+ delegates (search results). At least someone gives a more reasonable answer stating the contrary I think this is the best answer. Thanks.